# Joomla 2.5 where are Module Params stored?

Tags: joomla, parameters, module

I am able to use the module parameter in my module, but want to create a cronjob and need to access the module parameter in separate php file. So can anyone let me know how Joomla 2.5 stores module parameter? How can I access module parameter in my separate php file ?

Answer (score 1):

All module parameters are stored in the database table `#__modules`, field name `params`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

For Joomla 2.5+ you can create a CLI app that subclasses `JApplicationCLI`. e.g.

```
class myModuleCRONJob extends JApplicationCLI
{
    public function doExecute()
    {
        // Your code goes in here
    }
}
```

Doing this gives you complete access to `JDatabase`, `JModel` etc - you can see in the `/cli` directory of your Joomla installation several CLI apps are included.

Once you have the basics setup you can simply use JDatabase against the `#__modules` table etc to run your queries and actions.